# How can I fix dphys-swapfile?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, packages, pi-apps

I was trying to download some apps from pi apps, and then this output came in pi-apps: *Before dpkg, apt, or Pi-Apps will work, dphys-swapfile must be fixed.* I don't know, what this means exactly. Also when I try to run `sudo apt full-upgrade`, a error with an dphys-swapfile came.
Here is the terminal-outpout:                                     **What should I do?**

````
Will install these packages: curl libx11-6:armhf libxext6:armhf libegl1-mesa:armhf zlib1g:armhf libstdc++6:armhf libgl1-mesa-dri:armhf libasound2:armhf libpulse0:armhf libcom-err2:armhf libgmp10:armhf libp11-kit0:armhf libsystemd0:armhf libllvm9:armhf 
Running sudo apt update...
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Hit:5 https://mcpi-revival.github.io/mcpi-packages buster InRelease
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
apt update complete.
Some packages can be upgraded. Please consider running sudo apt full-upgrade.
Creating an empty apt-package to install the necessary apt packages...
It will be named: pi-apps-50a115ac
The pi-apps-50a115ac package is already installed. Inheriting its dependencies: curl, libasound2:armhf, libcom-err2:armhf, libegl1-mesa:armhf, libgl1-mesa-dri:armhf, libgmp10:armhf, libllvm9:armhf, libp11-kit0:armhf, libpulse0:armhf, libstdc++6:armhf, libsystemd0:armhf, libx11-6:armhf, libxext6:armhf, zlib1g:armhf
Depends: curl, libasound2:armhf, libcom-err2:armhf, libegl1-mesa:armhf, libgl1-mesa-dri:armhf, libgmp10:armhf, libllvm9:armhf, libp11-kit0:armhf, libpulse0:armhf, libstdc++6:armhf, libsystemd0:armhf, libx11-6:armhf, libxext6:armhf, zlib1g:armhf
Reinstalling the pi-apps-50a115ac package...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libasound2:armhf libasyncns0:armhf libatomic1:armhf libbsd0:armhf
  libcap2:armhf libcom-err2:armhf libdbus-1-3:armhf libdrm-amdgpu1:armhf
  libdrm-nouveau2:armhf libdrm-radeon1:armhf libdrm2:armhf libedit2:armhf
  libegl-mesa0:armhf libegl1:armhf libegl1-mesa:armhf libelf1:armhf
  libexpat1:armhf libffi6:armhf libflac8:armhf libgbm1:armhf libgcrypt20:armhf
  libgl1-mesa-dri:armhf libglapi-mesa:armhf libglvnd0:armhf libgmp10:armhf
  libgpg-error0:armhf libice6:armhf libllvm9:armhf liblz4-1:armhf
  liblzma5:armhf libogg0:armhf libp11-kit0:armhf libpulse0:armhf
  libsensors5:armhf libsm6:armhf libsndfile1:armhf libsystemd0:armhf
  libtinfo6:armhf libuuid1:armhf libva-wayland2 libvorbis0a:armhf
  libvorbisenc2:armhf libwayland-client0:armhf libwayland-server0:armhf
  libwrap0:armhf libx11-6:armhf libx11-xcb1:armhf libxau6:armhf
  libxcb-dri2-0:armhf libxcb-dri3-0:armhf libxcb-present0:armhf
  libxcb-sync1:armhf libxcb-xfixes0:armhf libxcb1:armhf libxdmcp6:armhf
  libxext6:armhf libxi6:armhf libxshmfence1:armhf libxtst6:armhf
  python-colorzero zlib1g:armhf
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  pi-apps-50a115ac*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
                                                              1 not fully installed or removed.
(Reading database ... 162892 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing pi-apps-50a115ac (1.0) ...
Job for dphys-swapfile.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status dphys-swapfile.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript dphys-swapfile, action "restart" failed.
● dphys-swapfile.service - dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dphys-swapfile.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-12-06 13:44:44 CET; 23ms ago
     Docs: man:dphys-swapfile(8)
  Process: 13755 ExecStart=/sbin/dphys-swapfile setup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13778 ExecStart=/sbin/dphys-swapfile swapon (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
 Main PID: 13778 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)

Dec 06 13:44:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file...
Dec 06 13:44:44 raspberrypi dphys-swapfile[13755]: want /var/swap=100MByte, checking existing: keeping it
Dec 06 13:44:44 raspberrypi dphys-swapfile[13778]: swapon: /var/swap: swapon failed: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler
Dec 06 13:44:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dphys-swapfile.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Dec 06 13:44:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dphys-swapfile.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 06 13:44:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file.
dpkg: error processing package dphys-swapfile (--configure):
 installed dphys-swapfile package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dphys-swapfile
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libva-wayland2 python-colorzero
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pi-apps-50a115ac
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
(Reading database ... 162893 files and directories currently installed.)
Job for dphys-swapfile.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status dphys-swapfile.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript dphys-swapfile, action "restart" failed.
● dphys-swapfile.service - dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dphys-swapfile.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-12-06 13:44:52 CET; 19ms ago
     Docs: man:dphys-swapfile(8)
  Process: 13905 ExecStart=/sbin/dphys-swapfile setup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13928 ExecStart=/sbin/dphys-swapfile swapon (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
 Main PID: 13928 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)

Dec 06 13:44:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file...
Dec 06 13:44:52 raspberrypi dphys-swapfile[13905]: want /var/swap=100MByte, checking existing: keeping it
Dec 06 13:44:52 raspberrypi dphys-swapfile[13928]: swapon: /var/swap: swapon failed: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler
Dec 06 13:44:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dphys-swapfile.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Dec 06 13:44:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dphys-swapfile.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 06 13:44:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file.
dpkg: error processing package dphys-swapfile (--configure):
 installed dphys-swapfile package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dphys-swapfile
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Apt finished.
Failed to install the packages!
APT reported these errors:
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libva-wayland2 python-colorzero
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pi-apps-50a115ac
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
(Reading database ... 162893 files and directories currently installed.)
Job for dphys-swapfile.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status dphys-swapfile.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript dphys-swapfile, action "restart" failed.
● dphys-swapfile.service - dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dphys-swapfile.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-12-06 13:44:52 CET; 19ms ago
     Docs: man:dphys-swapfile(8)
  Process: 13905 ExecStart=/sbin/dphys-swapfile setup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13928 ExecStart=/sbin/dphys-swapfile swapon (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
 Main PID: 13928 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)

Dec 06 13:44:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file...
Dec 06 13:44:52 raspberrypi dphys-swapfile[13905]: want /var/swap=100MByte, checking existing: keeping it
Dec 06 13:44:52 raspberrypi dphys-swapfile[13928]: swapon: /var/swap: swapon failed: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler
Dec 06 13:44:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dphys-swapfile.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Dec 06 13:44:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dphys-swapfile.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 06 13:44:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file.
dpkg: error processing package dphys-swapfile (--configure):
 installed dphys-swapfile package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dphys-swapfile
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Failed to install Minecraft Bedrock!
Need help? Copy the ENTIRE terminal output or take a screenshot.
Please ask on Github: https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps/issues/new/choose
Or on Discord: https://discord.gg/RXSTvaUvuu```
````

Comment: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1933730&hilit=dphys+swapfile#p1933730

Comment: what's the output of `ls -lh /var/swap` and `swapon --show`

Comment: This is the output of ls -lh... `-rw------- 1 root root 100M Nov  3  2020 /var/swap` and from swapon...: `nothing`